# How to associate 3 different models in to a 2 model relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

The gist of the matter is I want to know the best way to associate the below setup.

I have 2 customer models. `Individual Customer` & `Corporate Customer`.

I have another `Vehicle` model. Which I would like to maintain separately.

I would like to have a HMT model called `VehicleOwner`. Which now adds the r/ship of any of the two(2) customers as an owner & the vehicle.

The reason for this approach is an architecture design to allow the same vehicle to be migrated to other customers and not have every time a customer wants to add a vehicle; they keep adding a vehicle even if we have it.

**My question is this?**
How can I link in the Vehicle Owner. That the owner can either be an individual customer or a corporate customer.

Or is there another better way to map the two(2) customers with a vehicle.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Maina, if my answer helped you resolve your issue, can you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: I ended up not associating it. I just used validations to make sure this relation exists. I was unable to use your solution at the time.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for **Polymorphic association** in Rails, in your case it would be, `VehicleOwner` model should look like

```
belongs_to :customer, polymorphic: true
```

In `IndividualCustomer` and `CorporateCustomer` models

```
has_many :vehicle_owners, as: :customer
```

This is just an example of how to implement this, you can read more about in official Rails guides

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Hope that helps!